# Imitating fullscreen gesture of MPMoviePlayerController on UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

When the user makes a zoom gesture, I need the image to animate to fullscreen, without bouncing around or having to gesture more than once. Movies played using MPMoviePlayerController have exactly this behaviour.

I note some people have implemented something similar using scrollview/webview, but that doesn't give the same effect, and often requires several gestures to fully zoom an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the pinch using UIPinchGestureRecognizer which has a scale getter that tells you how much the user pinched in/out.